# stripe.createToken() is not a function

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe in node.js.

I need to create a stripe token with bank details. For that I am using the below code which is given in the stripe documentation:

```
stripe.createToken('bank_account', {
  country: 'US',
  currency: 'usd',
  routing_number: '110000000',
  account_number: '000123456789',
  account_holder_name: 'Jenny Rosen',
  account_holder_type: 'individual',
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log("result", result);
});
```

But I am getting this error, "stripe.createToken() is not a function".

I have also tried "stripe.tokens.create({
  bank_account: {})" but it is not giving the token "account".

Need someone's valuable help.

Comment: For node the syntax should be `stripe.tokens.create`, what's the full, specific error you are getting when using that syntax? what version of the stripe-node sdk are you using?

Comment: @Coder Have you fixed this? I am also getting the same error in my React Native code.

Comment: Same error for me.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found so far is to do the following import in your root document: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#import-as-a-side-effect.

```
import '@stripe/stripe-js';
// rest of your imports
```

Other methods also posted in the Stripe JS readme.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself, but the stripe documentation is the best to reference. https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_bank_account

```
const token = await stripe.tokens.create({
  bank_account: {
    country: 'US',
    currency: 'usd',
    account_holder_name: 'Jenny Rosen',
    account_holder_type: 'individual',
    routing_number: '110000000',
    account_number: '000123456789',
  },
});
```